# Regular expression (Reg exp). Why this works?

Tags: python, regex

So, I am trying to get my head around regexp. The first query doesn't give me the result but the second one does. I am not able to make sense, why that is.

I am trying to tokenize the sentence,

```
text = 'The interest does not exceed 8.25%.'
pattern = r'\w+|\d+\.\d+\%|[^\w+\s]+'
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(pattern)
tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

This gives me

```
['The', 'interest', 'does', 'not', 'exceed', '8', '.', '25', '%']
```

And I want

```
['The', 'interest', 'does', 'not', 'exceed', '8.25%']
I get my result with,
pattern = r'\d+\.\d+\%|\w+|[^\w+\s]+'
```

Why does it work with the second pattern? Shouldn't both the queries work?

Comment: typo `\w+|d+\.\d+\%` => `\w+|\d+\.\d+\%` missing backslash before first 'd'

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  Sorry, its a typo in my post, ill edit it. I used it with the slash in my code. Thanks for pointing it out though

Comment: `r'|d+\.\d+\%|\w+|[^\w+\s]+'` typo here as well

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Just noticed. Thanks for improving my post

Comment: Probably, `r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?%|\w+|[^\w\s]+'` wil be the best here unless you do not want to get `20%` like tokens.

Comment: i guess you are simply matching all nonspace characters... you could simply do: `re.findall("\\S+",text)` or even you can split on the `\s` ie `text.split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that `\w` matches letters, digits and underscores. Since the expression comes first in your ored expressions, it's prioritary.

```
['The', 'interest', 'does', 'not', 'exceed', '8', '.',     '25',  '%']
  \w+       \w+       \w+     \w+     \w+    \w+  [^\w\s]+  \w+  [^\w\s]+
```

The second expression never has a chance to match because it's partly consumed by the first one.

Invert the ored expressions:

```
r'\d+\.\d+\%|\w+|[^\w\s]+'
```

just a test with the basic `re` module:

```
text = 'The interest does not exceed 8.25%.'
pattern = r'\d+\.\d+%|\w+|[^\w\s]+'

print(re.findall(pattern,text))
```

prints:

```
['The', 'interest', 'does', 'not', 'exceed', '8.25%', '.']
```

(note that you don't have to escape `%`)